# Скачать определенные файлы с сервера

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

У меня есть переменная string ,в которой хранятся имена файлов через разделитель,которые нужно скачать.Вот так

```
h_IFFTwTEhM.jpg|school.JPG|u4NosPuDqwE.jpg|
```

Эти изображения находятся в папке *img* на сервере.Подскажите как мне их все скачать.Как скачать один файл я знаю.

```
string file = Request.MapPath(cookname["filename"]);
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + info.Name.Replace(".resources", ""));
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", info.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(info.FullName);
        Response.End();
```

А как тут поступить?

Comment: `foreach (var file in filenames.Split('|')) DownloadFile(file)`.

Comment: @VladD,А в каком пространстве имен DownloadFile?

Comment: Ну, вы ж говорите, что можете загрузить _один_ файл по имени? Оформьте это в процедуру `DownloadFile`.

Comment: А вообще для загрузки файла используется [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144194%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Честно говоря,не работал раньше с WebClient.DownloadFile. В этом то и дело,что один то я скачать могу.Проблема и была в основном в самой скачки нескольких файлом,а не получения имен отдельно через разделить.

Comment: Подождите. Если вы можете легко скачать один, то почему нельзя в цикле сделать то же самое несколько раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подобная необходимость была и у меня я решил её следующим образом: на сервере создаю архив и его отдаю пользователю пример моей функции ниже

```
public string GetZippedFiles(string fileName,string path)
{
     var src = Path.Combine(pathOfSave,path);
     fileName = String.Format("{0}.zip",fileName);
     string dst = Path.Combine(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(pathOfSave, path)).Parent.FullName, fileName);
     var foldersList = GetFoldersForArchive(src);
     using (var fs = new FileStream(dst, FileMode.Create))
     using (var zip = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Create,false,Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866")))
     {
         foreach(var folder in foldersList)
              foreach (var file in folder.GetFiles())
                  {
                      zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName,String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", file.Directory.Name, file.Name));
                  }
        }
        return dst;
    }
```

небольшая поясниловка: на вход имя файл для архива, и путь где брать файлы для архива