# Загрузка нескольких файлов с сервера ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Приложение на ASP.NET MVC 5. Загрузку одного файла реализую вот таким образом

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult SaveFile(string fileName)
{
   FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileSource + fileName);

   var doc = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileSource + fileName);
   return File(doc, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
}
```

Но если файлов много, можно ли сразу получить всю коллекцию подобным вызовом? Или это необходимо реализовывать по другому?

Comment: в целях экономии трафика, на сервере можно создать архив состоящий из нескольких файлов и отдать его клиенту, [пример создания архива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423780/179270)

Comment: @Bald спасибо за ответ, но файлы весят от силы 20-30 кб, хотелось бы именно инициализировать их закачку

Comment: код в вопросе не "инициализирует закачку", а отвечает на запрос. Посылайте с клиента пять запросов, отправляйте в ответ на них пять файлов.

Comment: @Igor Т.е. именно все с клиента браузера, на самом сервере нельзя так вернуть?

Comment: @Unnamed Можно... по крайней мере протоколом http это предусмотрено, конкретную реализацию на дотнэт - не подскажу.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а можете ссылку на документацию показать? Или примеры реализации на любых платформах...

Comment: Нашел вот такое: https://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/ Можно попробовать написать свою реализацию `ActionResult` с таким поведением

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Множественное_содержимое, самое первое что можно нагуглить =)

Comment: Я думаю вот это будет ответом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069730/how-to-create-a-multipart-http-response-with-asp-net-core

Comment: @Unnamed, как адаптируете код под свою задачу — напишите ответ, полезно будет.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал предварительно изучить вопрос поддержки браузерами этой фичи, она не на слуху и возможно толковой поддержки нет. Всё что я пока находил относится к настолько древним версиям браузеров, что стыдно показывать. А вообще идея хорошая.

Comment: В комментариях пишут, что работает только в FF, так что остается для полноценной работы только с клиентской стороны слать запросы и скачивать по одному